# How to use Python BeautifulSoup when website URL does not change?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract data from a website using BeautifulSoup (or other web scraping tools) although am struggling because the URL of website is the same before and after you log-in as a user. I do not want to publicly share the website address here but if needed will in a comment below. For a simple example, let's use "example.com" as a reference:

When you first navigate to abc.com, the URL is exactly that (example.com). To log-in, the user clicks a login button and is then taken to "example.com/login". The problem is then, after successfully logging in, the URL returns to "example.com" although the HTML code changes. When I try to scrape with BS4 and get the HTML code of the site, I am getting the pre-login-in HTML code although need to access the HTML after logging in.

Here is what I have:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.example.com/').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html5lib')

name = soup.find('pointer') 
# this is the class I'm trying to search for, although am not able to find 
# because it is not part of 
# the HTML code in the **pre-log-in** - the class is part of the HTML after 
# logging in 

print(soup.prettify())
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Have your tried grabbing your session cookie from developer tools in your browser after you have logged in and then passing it in the header of your request?

Comment: This is a bit out of my skill level but I can try to google / learn how to do this. I'll be back then! :)

Comment: Could you provide an example of what the session cookie looks like (the formatting)? I'm not sure what to look for but I am in the cookies of the particular website

Comment: It would depend on the website, but it is always passed in the headers. Look into https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/storage/cookies on advice on how to find it, or even better look at the session object from ```requests``` library https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced. It will manage the headers for you.

Answer (score 1):

How about using selenium to log in and then passing the source code of the page to beautifulsoup, and work from there? Would probably be the simpliest way to achieve that.

Comment: In this case I would only have to do it once at the beginning of the session correct (when I initialize my web driver and run it for the first time)?

Comment: Yeah, i did myself something similar, where i first fetched a website, scrolled down to load the entire page and then imported the pagesource to the source which beautifulsoup has to fetch